# Finding distribution function when pdf is $f(x) = |x|$ for $ -1 < x < 1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

In my probability/stats course, they have defined a probability density function as:

$$f(x) = |x|\quad,\quad -1 < x < 1$$

I am having difficulty with how they have integrated this to find the cumulative distribution function:

$F(x) = (1-x^2)/2, \quad -1 \leq x \leq 0$, and

$F(x) = (1+x^2)/2, \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: I would have been happy to receive a reply [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733639/solving-binomial-distribution-inequality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
|x|, & -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} = \begin{cases}
-x, & -1 \leq x < 0 \\
x, & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

When finding the CDF, you must partition the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$ appropriately and consider each case. In this situation, we must consider $(-\infty, 1)$, $[-1, 0)$, $[0, 1)$, and $[1, \infty)$.

**Case 1** is the interval $(-\infty, -1)$:

For any $x < -1$, $F(x) = 0$, since if $x < -1$:
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\underbrace{f(t)}_{=\text{ }0\text{ for } t < -1}\text{ d}t = \int_{-\infty}^{x}0\text{ d}t = 0$$

**Case 2** is the interval $[-1, 0)$:

Suppose now that $-1 \leq x < 0$. Then
$$\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{-1}\underbrace{f(t)}_{=\text{ }0\text{ for } t < -1}\text{ d}t + \int_{-1}^{x}\underbrace{f(t)}_{=\text{ }-t\text{ for } -1 \leq t < 0}\text{ d}t\\
&= 0 + \int_{-1}^{x}-t\text{ d}t \\
&= -\left[\dfrac{t^2}{2} \right]^{x}_{-1} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}\left(1 - x^2\right)\text{.}
\end{align}$$

**Case 3** is the interval $[0, 1)$:

Suppose that $0 \leq x < 1$. Then
$$\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{-1}\underbrace{f(t)}_{=\text{ }0\text{ for } t < -1}\text{ d}t + \int_{-1}^{0}\underbrace{f(t)}_{=\text{ }-t\text{ for } -1 \leq t < 0}\text{ d}t + \int_{0}^{x}\underbrace{f(t)}_{=\text{ }t\text{ for } 0 \leq t < 1}\text{ d}t\\
&=0 + \int_{-1}^{0}-t\text{ d}t + \int_{0}^{x}t\text{ d}t \\
&= \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{2}(1-0^2)}_{\text{from Case 2}} + \left[\dfrac{t^2}{2} \right]^x_{0} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2} \\
&= \dfrac{1+x^2}{2} 
\end{align}$$

**Case 4** is the interval $[1, \infty)$:

If $x \geq 1$, we have
$$\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\text{ d}t \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{1}f(t)\text{ d}t + \int_{1}^{x}\underbrace{f(t)}_{=\text{ }0\text{ for } t > 1}\text{ d}t \\
&= \underbrace{\dfrac{1+1^2}{2}}_{\text{from Case 3}} + 0 \\
&= 1
\end{align}$$

Thus,
$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x < -1 \\
\dfrac{1-x^2}{2}, & -1 \leq x < 0 \\
\dfrac{1+x^2}{2}, & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
1, & x \geq 1\text{.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.** Rewrite $f(x)$ as

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-x & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
x & \phantom{-}0 \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

and then integrate $f(x)$ to get $F(x)$, keeping in mind that

- $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$
- $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$
- $F(x)$ is continuous in this case, since there are no atoms

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for this. However, when I try this: I get $F(x) = (1/2)*(1-x^2)$ by evaluating: $\int_{-1}^x (-u) du$. However, I do not get the other part when I evaluate: $\int_0^x u du = x^2/2$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ThomasMoore: You have to add the right constant in order to satisfy the last two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

for $x\le 0$, $F(x)=\int_{-1}^xf(u)du=\int_{-1}^x(-u)du=\frac{1-x^2}{2}$.

For $x\gt 0$, $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\int_0^xudu=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{1+x^2}{2}$

Comment: Hi @herb steinberg Where does the factor of (1/2) come from in the first term $F(x)$ for the $x > 0$ case?  Thanks.

Comment: The cdf starts at $-1$.  $\int_{-1}^0f(u)du=\frac{1}{2}$.  My expression computes $\int_0^x$ for $x\gt 0$ separatety and adds it in.